# ANY good/simple examples of Ajax in Cake 1.3 without using deprecated helpers?

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I've used AJAX a lot in PHP, but now I'm trying to learn CakePHP, and haven't been able to ANY good/simple examples of how to use AJAX with CakePHP 1.3.  The only examples I've been able to find are for paging (not what I need), or use the deprecated helpers while forcing you to include scriptaculous or prototype.

Are there ANY good/simple examples of how to use AJAX w/ CakePHP 1.3?  Or is it something someone could explain here?

**All I want to do is** have the user click a link, which retrieves the contents of a php file, and inserts it into a div.  The contents of the php file would be altered based on some POST or GET variables sent w/ the ajax call.  Seems simple enough :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the pattern that I use in CakePHP 1.3.x.  The process is generally:

1. Creating alternative json-oriented layout and view files
2. Detecting if the incoming request is AJAX
3. Explicitly rendering the alternative json layout/view instead of text/html

Be sure to include RequestHandler component and JsHelper in your app controller.

In a given controller:

```
function test() {
    if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
        $this->set('data', $this->data);
        // Explicit call to render an ajax response, using a layout and view made specifically for ajax
        $this->layout = 'json';
        $this->render('ajax_test');    
    }
    // else render views/controllername/test.ctp like normal
}
```

Your app/views/layouts/json.ctp file:

```
<?php
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate");
    header('Content-Type: text/x-json');
    header("X-JSON: ".$content_for_layout);

    echo $content_for_layout;
?>
```

Your app/views/controllername/ajax_test.ctp file should contain only:

```
<?php echo $js->object($data); ?>
```

Now, on your page that's actually going to make an ajax call, it might look something like this, with jQuery code:

```
<div id='status'></div>
<?php echo $form->create('Test', array('id'=>'testForm')),
           $form->input('message'),
           $form->end();
?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('#testForm').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // interrupt form submission
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/controllername/test",
        data: $('#testForm').serialize(),
        success: function(data, textStatus, xmlHttpRequest) {               
            $("#status").html(data.Test.message);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("There was a problem processing the request: " + jqXHR);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is what you call simple, eh?  :)  I've never used JSON - was just hoping for a simple example of AJAX - even if it may not be the most ideal.  In this example - if I made a file that held my dynamic content that I wanted to pull in - how would I display it?  I don't want to change the entire layout - I just want to add the contents to a div that already exists on the page.

Comment: The code above returns json which is parsable by the calling javascript on a given page.  json is a common transfer format for ajax, with alternatives being raw html (not recommended) and xml.   From your response it sounds like you're lacking a basic understanding of ajax in general.  You may be better of running through some basic ajax tutorials and getting a better understanding before trying to integrate ajax into your Cake application.

Comment: Ok - so ignoring the JSON vs HTML thing (I can look into JSON asap) - your example would require me to rewrite my entire layout view file y/n?  And if I parse the JSON data - how would I add that to my div?  Again - maybe I'm not using AJAX the BEST way - but it shouldn't go from being able to do a 2-line jquery call in normal PHP to rewriting entire pages in Cake.  Maybe I assume wrong - but - jsut didn't think cake would make it MORE difficult to do a normally simple AJAX call.

Comment: You're confusing what I've provided above with the rendering of a full page.  This doesn't affect your existing views and layouts.  The above code is used when an ajax call is made to your Cake app *only*, as you don't want to render a full page and return it in that case.  You want to send something back that the JS can easily process. I'll update the example above with what the javascript on your page might look like.

Comment: Very nice Tyler. Just wanted to add/confirm that you should work with relative links.

`url: "/controllername/test"` 

could probably be generated with `Helper::url(array('controller' => 'controllername', 'action' => 'test'));` ?

Sorry if I'm wrong, I'm new to CakePHP. Tyler your answer was very helpful. +1.

Comment: That's fine assuming you're writing js inline in your view file.  I always move to an external .js file which cannot leverage the helper.

Answer (score 1):

You can check http://wakeusup.com/2011/06/kkajaxify-plugin-cakephp/ for a great ajax plugin

Answer (score 0):

I usually include a js file in the required view `$this->Html->script('file', false);`. Then, in that file I do all the necessary AJAX stuff (build the data to be sent, send it to another page, bring the data back and finally show it in the required div).

But be aware, that the file the data is sent to needs to be relative to the app's root. This is the only way I got it working (`$.get('/users/view/5');` - in jQuery)

Comment: So - basically you use AJAX normally without using any special CakePHP stuff?

Comment: No, not at all. I use Cake only to include the JS file in the view. This way I am able to code in JavaScript as I did before, which is, at least for me, a big advantage, because I don't have to learn anything extra from Cake to be able to write a simple script.